# How to parse set of properties in unspecified order?

Tags: parsing, scala

I have a Regex parser that processes a custom property file. In my file, I have the following structure:

```
...
[NodeA]
propA=val1
propB=val2
propC=val3

[NodeB]
...
```

I defined a parser that processes NodeA as follows:

```
lazy val parserA: Parser[String] = "propA" ~> "=" ~> mPropA 
lazy val parserB: Parser[String] =  
...

lazy val nodeA: Parser[NodeA] = "[" ~> "NodeA" ~> "]" ~> parserA ~> parserB ~> parserB ^^ { 
   case iPropA ~ iPropB ~ iPropC => new NodeA(iPropA, iPropB, iPropC)
}
```

This works fine as it stands. The problem is if NodeA comes with a different property order, in which case I get a parsing error. For example:

```
[NodeA]
propC=val3
propA=val1
propB=val2
```

Is there any way to define my parser such that it accepts an unspecified ordering of NodeA's properties?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Just parse the string before the equal sign and then look if it is correct. I see no need for `propA`, `propB` etc.

Comment: There is a choice combinator: `|` as well as closures: `*` (unbounded), `+` (positive). ... And "_much, much more!_".

Comment: @sschaef maybe the snippet was confusing. That is what I'm doing. I'm parsing the string before the equal sign to get all properties. At the end, I create my NodeA object based on the properties I read, which must be passed on an specific order. I can read them all but how can I guarantee they are passed in order?

Comment: @RandallSchulz I could use choice (|), with something like (parserA | parserB | parserC | ...) which would capture the first one, but then I would need to do the same until I read all properties. How could you use option to process remaining properties once one is matched?

Comment: That's why I mentioned the closure combinators. Just tack on (postfix) the `*` or `+` (I think there are arbitrarily bounded closures, too).

Comment: thanks Randall, I'll give it a try as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still I have the feeling not understanding your problem, but what about:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.JavaTokenParsers

object Test extends App with JavaTokenParsers {

  case class Prop(name: String, value: String)
  case class Node(name: String, propA: Prop, propB: Prop, propC: Prop)

  lazy val prop = (ident <~ "=") ~ ident ^^ {
    case p ~ v => (p, v)
  }

  lazy val node = "[" ~> ident <~ "]"

  lazy val props = repN(3, prop) ^^ {
    _.sorted map Prop.tupled
  }

  lazy val nodes = rep(node ~ props) ^^ {
    _ map { case node ~ List(a, b, c) => Node(node, a, b, c) }
  }

  val in =
"""[NodeA]
propA=val1
propB=val2
propC=val3

[NodeB]
propC=val3
propA=val1
propB=val2"""

  println(parseAll(nodes, in))
}
```

Comment: This would do it. I can then handle this on the Node constructor. Thanks!